# How can I resize a background-image to fit my element (without set width) in CSS 2?

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I have to remain compliant with IE 8, so no CSS3 only answers will do.

I know that I can use the background-image property, but I can't use background-size property, as it is CSS3 only.

I know that I can resize the image and then simply apply it, however, I don't know exactly what the element's size will be (I don't mind setting height to a "px" value, but I always use percentages with width, even for the body element [nobody likes a horizontal scroll-bar!]).

I have to center some text over this background-image, so I also tried just inserting an `<img>` tag and then putting the text in a span element with `position: absolute;` but I doubt that using the `left` and `top` properties to kind-of "micromanage" this positioning will prove to look the same in all browsers, screen sizes, and screen resolutions (please, correct me, if I'm wrong, but this will be a public site, and has to look the same for everybody). That having been said, I am not opposed to using this approach if I can be assured that using positioning will look the same, regardless of the user's personal browser, screen, or resolution choices.

Is there any way to handle this without relying solely on CSS3?

I don't think there is any reason to post any markup or CSS, but let me know if it would help and I'll be happy to.

Just to clarify: I need the whole image to "fit" in the element and I am not really concerned about aspect ratio.

Comment: +1 for responsive thinking

Comment: @derek_duncan Thanks for the upvote! Although, I'm not sure what you mean by "responsive thinking" but if you can clarify, I will be sure to keep whatever approach that is in mind, for future reference, and not forget it :) Thanks again!

Comment: Responsive design is building your website to adapt to any device.  Many times people use media queries to change the css of elements depending on the screen size.  However, the use of percents often accomplish the biggest part of responsive design.

Comment: @derek_duncan OIC, thanks for letting me know. Yeah, I used to (when I first started web design) use px for widths and heights, and pretty much treated it as my only measurement. BIG MISTAKE as different browsers were displaying my elements in different places, in relation to each other (still don't necessarily get that, I would expect it to be different with different resolutions, but with the same screen and resolution, a pixel is a pixel is a pixel, I thought). Anyway, now I know there are times when I want to use px (mainly for height), percentages (mainly for width), and even em.

Comment: Spot on dude.  I wish more people thought this way with their code.

Comment: @derek_duncan Man! It is good to have some feedback on this! I wasn't sure if it was the right approach or not, really, I just knew (after some pretty simple "Googling") how they each worked and over time just tried to apply them as I expected their behavior to treat different browsers, resolutions, etc. I'm glad to see I am on to something. P.S. I definitely hate using Javascript/jQuery (or any scripting language, for that matter) for non-dynamic styling, unless there is NO other way. It's just a freaking waste to use scripting where CSS is enough.

Comment: Indeed.  But often CSS is not capable(rather supported) for various tasks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28916/discussion-between-derek-duncan-and-voidking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this quite simply:

**html:**

```
<div class="holder">
    <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
    <div class="text">Testing text</div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.holder {position:relative; width:100%; overflow:hidden;} //this has overflow hidden so it treats the image like a background and hides any extra
.holder img {position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; z-index:1;}
.holder .text {position:relative; z-index:2; text-align:center;} //this is positioned relative so the div grows to the size of the text
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UANFm/2/

Comment: I have to step out and clean somebody's computer before they lose their mind (they can't seem to stay off of those coupon sites) but I will be back soon to check these answers. Thanks, so much, for your help. Be back soon!

Comment: There is one problem with your scenario. I want the full pic to "fit" inside the .holder div

Comment: Just noticed it does work if you set the `.holder img` with `height: 100%;` (also I adjusted the width of the same rule to 10% because I need several "buttons" to sit side by side. (Yes, I know they're not actually buttons, but jQuery will make them behave as such, when all is said and done.

Comment: Thank you so much for this non-JavaScript/non-jQuery way of doing it! If you add: `height: 100%;` to the `.holder img` rule in your answer (to remain true to my OP), you've got yourself an accept. :) Thanks again!

Comment: ah right you never said you wanted the whole image, in that case you would be better off using jquery to assign the height of the container div: http://jsfiddle.net/UANFm/3/

Comment: Ummm but your answer does work perfectly if you just add the height: 100% rule, as stated just above

Comment: but if you give the image both a width and height the aspect ratio is not kept properly, if you are also need to keep the ratio of the image a better option would be to use something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UANFm/5/

Comment: Also, I clarified my question to reflect that I wanted the whole image to "fit" in the element.

Comment: Ah, right, but I do NOT care about the aspect ratio (I seldom do for things like this). The image is nothing more sophisticated than something you could do in paint. Just used for a button image, it is a rectangle of color that fades in and out.

Comment: ah ok then the percentage height should be fine for you

Answer (score 2):

Very tough without javascript.

You might be able to add it as a normal image, set the postition to relative and z-index it under all the other content, then set width 100%. But this is still a bit of a hackish way and one that I haven't tested.

**Edit** try this: http://jsfiddle.net/xTgCY/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSaATzueHSd2rQXCWUQXFXc1sFAx3tNXBj-px5bU64D4ji5rmF6cw">
        <div class="content">aihadfuigh iaghdf aoisyhif o[iayhdf oiahdfio sadf</div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 0;
   top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't mind using javascript or jQuery, if that's how it needs to be done, but I'm afraid I don't know how I would go about that approach. I also have use of C#.net, but I don't think that would help here.

Comment: I have to step out and clean somebody's computer before they lose their mind (they can't seem to stay off of those coupon sites) but I will be back soon to check these answers. Thanks, so much, for your help. Be back soon!