# CSS Vertically align text inside image button

Tags: css

Im having trouble vertically aligning text inside a image button.
Vertical-align: middle doesnt seem to work.

Here what i got so far:

```
#navbar ul {
    padding-top: 10px;
    float:left;
}

#navbar li {    
    background-image:url("../images/btns.png");
    width: 78px;
    height:32px;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style:none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way to fix this is to give a `line-height` for the `li` same as that of its own height.

http://jsfiddle.net/KHBG4/

```
#navbar ul {
     padding-top: 10px;
     float:left;
 }
 #navbar li {
     background-image:url("http://placehold.it/78x32");
    float:left;
     width: 78px;
     height:32px;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 12px;
     list-style:none;
     line-height:32px;
 }
```

Comment: hmm.. yeah most cases like this line-height may be a quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align` can only be used with inline elements. That having been said, I know img tags are "inline-block" so not really sure what to expect there, but I don't think you mean to vertically align the img, but rather the text, so you need a separate inline tag (span would do fine) and use "position" and "vertical-align" to set it up right.

I have had a recent post about that very issue here:

[How can I resize a background-image to fit my element (without set width) in CSS 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216493/how-can-i-resize-a-background-image-to-fit-my-element-without-set-width-in-css)

Comment: @Sebastian Yup, check out my post, I did it the same way as you. The answer therein also respects IE 8, in case that's an issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the simplest route of giving your button `padding-top` (and reducing it's height by that number of course).

It's not truly "auto-centered", as it won't be centered if you change the height without updating the padding, but - it works and it's clean and easy, and simple to update.

Comment: may look different in different browsers/screen resolutions though, right?

Comment: @VoidKing - It should not - I've always used this method and have never had any cross-browser display issues.

Comment: Okay, I guess it just depends on how you set it up

Comment: @VoidKing - I'm unsure how you would set it up that would cause issues, but... I can't speak for other people's code.

Comment: All I mean to say is that I've done it before in my early days, but it must have been something else.